# Why does ng-click not work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Moved this question to this post - [Angular events, ng-click, do not work with other libraries Dojo, Knockout, KendoUI, ESRI JSAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35075313/angular-events-ng-click-do-not-work-with-other-libraries-dojo-knockout-kendo)

No matter what I try, ng-click does not work.  However, onclick works. Inside the scope, wiring up an on click event dos not work. What is going on?

EDIT: I can call the $scope.myClick() from the command line. But it will not hit the breakpoint. It will show an alert window, but if this is called from within HTML directive, the function is not hit.

EDIT 2: heres a plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/kK3NmWB9wfOopG7m5MYv?p=preview

EDIT 3: Ok, so the plunker works, but the horrible application I need to add angular to must messing with something in angular. Any ideas what could be breaking Angular in an existing app? This other app uses dojo, dojo loaders, and require.js. Everything works, except for the ng-click event.

EDIT 4: I commented out an Init() call from this application which loads Dojo, Kendo UI, Knockout, and ESRI JSAPI components, and this Angular code with ng-click works. My gut feeling is knockout is messing with this. Is it possible to completely isolate Angular from the rest of this application? Any suggestions?

here is the app:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp ', []);
```

directive:

```
myApp.directive('rapidReport',
function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E'
    }
});

  <div class="ls-rapidReports">
        <div ng-app="myApp">
            <div id="rapidreportCtrl" ng-controller="rrController">
                <button type="button" ng-click="myClick()">hehe</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

controller:

```
myApp.controller('rrController',
function rrController($scope) {

    $scope.myClick = function () {
        debugger;
    };


});
```

Comment: What version of angularjs you are using and on what browsers have you tried it on?

Comment: rebuild you complete code in a the stackoverflow code editor or in plunker so it is easier for people to help debug.

Comment: tried in chrome and FF, version v1.4.7

Comment: what do yo mean by rebuild?

Comment: I just tested your plunker and ng-click did work. Am I missing something?

Comment: To answer your EDIT 3, if you have a javascript error somewhere it could stop the rest of your code working properly. You need to look at the console and find out what is erroring.

Comment: rapid-report directive is not used in your view. Why do you refer to it?

Comment: There are no errors in the console. Plunker updated without the directive.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp ', []);
```

which should be:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []); //myApp without space before '
```

-

**EDIT**: Now I see it fixed in the plnkr. If you infact try to add the space again in myApp declaration you will see the following error message in the console.

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

As you can deduct from the error log, the app declaration in the `script.js` wasn't matching with the one in the ng-app directive in `index.html`, so the app wasn't working.

Comment: already caught. Does not work in existing non-angular dojo/kendo ui application.

Comment: @user714157 I suggest you to open a new question with an excerpt of the code of the non-angular app, as the plnkr you linked is now working. It's very hard to tell you why isn't working without seeing the code.

Comment: @user714157 glad I helped. Mark my answer as accepted if it helped you to solve the problem in this specific case. Thank you.